# Is there a Python function that calculates weights according to duplicated id's?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset, where rows = clients, columns = products. Each client may have multiple rows, according to the amount of orders.

Goal = a new column with a weight

Example:

```
ID  Weight
1    1
2    1/2
2    1/2
```

is there a function for it?

Comment: Can you show us what your data looks like?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? This is probably a custom function that needs to be written. Can you more clearly explain what you are struggling with, what your dataset looks like, what your expected results are, and the logic to achieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to get the number of elements in each list, and divide 1 by this value to get the weight of each row.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 2, 7: 1, 8: 0, 9: 1}})

df['dupweight'] = 1 / df.groupby('a')['a'].transform(len)
df.sort_values('a')
```

```
   a  dupweight
1  0  0.250000
2  0  0.250000
5  0  0.250000
8  0  0.250000
0  1  0.333333
7  1  0.333333
9  1  0.333333
3  2  0.333333
4  2  0.333333
6  2  0.333333
```